# Convergence rate of steepest descent by newton's method

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

Help me to understand the proof that is given in the "Numerical Optimizaton" by Jorge Nocedal & Stephen J. Wright. The theorem says that at a near point $x_0$ then $\{x_k\}\to x^*$ by taking $x_{k+1}=x_k+p_{k}$ where $p_k$ is a descent direction and $\nabla^2f_kp_k=-\nabla f_k$ and the rate of convergence is quadratic and $\{\nabla f_k\}\to 0$ also converges quadratically.
[image]

After the step (3.32), (Since the Hessian is non singular there is a radius...) I get lost, can someone help me unserstanding this?

Comment: Newton proofs tend to be slightly opaque. If a continuous matrix $A$ is invertible at $x^*$ then there is a neighbourhood of $x^*$ such that $\|A(x)\| \le 2 \|A(x^*)\|$ for $x$ in this neighbourhood. Here $A$ is the **inverse** of the Hessian.

Comment: Could you recommend me where to look for a proof of that proposition? ($A$ continuous and non singular the there is...)

Comment: Since $\det$ is continuous, if follows that for some neighbourhood that $A(x)$ is invertible, Since $x \mapsto \|A(x)\|$ is continuous, it follows that in some neighbourhood that $0<\|A(x)\| \le 2 \|A(x^*)\|$. Now take the intersection of the neighbourhoods.